# How to validate date ranges with HTML5 date inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

The function `TwoFunctions()` is called when the 'Find Flights' button in the HTML is clicked. It will then call the two remaining functions.

The first one, `Format()`, is used to check whether the format entered is correct and if the a date has been entered at all. This function seems to work fine and validates/invalidates correctly.

But the second one, `validDate()` doesn't seem to invalidate dates three months in the future or an arrival time being before a departure time and was wondering why?

I have used alerts to check that the function is being called but it is still stating that 'Dates are validated' when they should not be.

```
var departuredate = document.getElementById("departdate").value; 
var arrivaldate = document.getElementById("arrivedate").value;

var months3 = 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //3 months 
var departuserspecifiedTime = departuredate.getTime();
var arrivaluserspecifiedTime = arrivaldate.getTime();  
var currentTime = CurrentDate.getTime(); //current time and date
var departdifference = departuserspecifiedTime - currentTime; //difference between departure time and the current time
var arrivaldifference = arrivaluserspecifiedTime - currentTime; //difference between arrival time and the current time

function TwoFunctions() {
    departuredate = document.getElementById("departdate").value;
    arrivaldate = document.getElementById("arrivedate").value;
    //alert(departuredate);
    //alert(arrivaldate);

    var result = Format();
    var result1 = validDate();

    if (result == true) {
        result1;
    } else {
        alert("Error 123");
    }
    return result
}

function validDate() {
    alert('debug');
    if (departdifference <= (1000 * 60 * 60)) //if the departure time is in the past or within an hour of the current time, it is invalidated as it is too soon
    {
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Date selected is in the past";
        document.MyForm.departdate.focus();
        document.getElementById("departdate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        return false;
    } else if (arrivaldifference <= (1000 * 60 * 60)) //if the arrival time is in the past or within an hour of the current time, it is invalidated as it is too soon
    {
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Date selected is in the past";
        document.MyForm.arrivedate.focus();
        document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        return false;
    } else if (departdifference && arrivaldifference >= months3) //if the departure/arrival date is over 3 months away from todays date it is invalidated
    {
        document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Only 3 months          advance booking is allowed";
        document.getElementById("departdate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        return false;
    } else if (arrivaluserspecifiedTime < departuserspecifiedTime) // if the arrival date is before the departure date it is invalidated 
    {
        alert("Arrival date selected is before the departure date");
        document.getElementById("departdate").focus();
        document.getElementById("arrivedate").focus();
        document.getElementById("departdate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        document.getElementById("arrivedate").style.border = '1px solid red';
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Dates are validated');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically I am wondering why the function above is invalidating all entries and not invalidating them as I had hoped the code would.

Comment: I am happy to upload the Format function if you think my problem might be in there.

Comment: I have improved your question by choosing a somewhat better  title and creating a runnable code snippet. However, for the moment the code snippet still has a run-time error. Please make some final modifications to the code so that it demonstrates your problem. (You can edit your question, there will also be a link that allows you to edit the code snippet conveniently.)